# Why is "auto const&" not read-only?

Tags: c++, reference, constants, auto

```
#include <tuple>

int main()
{
    int xa = 1;
    int ya = 2;

    auto const& [xb, yb] = std::tuple<int&, int&>(xa, ya);

    xb = 9; // Shouldn't this be read-only?

    return xa + ya;
}
```

This not only compiles, but returns 11.

So two questions:

1. Why am I allowed to write to xb when it is specified as auto const&?  Shouldn't this fail to compile?
2. Why can't I replace "auto const&" with "auto&" and have it compile?  Both Clang (6.0) and g++ (7.3) complain with an error message like "non-const lvalue reference of type<...> cannot bind to temporary of type tuple<...>"

Thanks!

Comment: Agreed that this is a duplicate, but this is a much simpler example.

Comment: Hooray for more twisted initialization rules...

Comment: Is it better to mark the other question a duplicate of this one because this question is so much clearer?

Comment: @Galik Yes, if this one gets a good answer.

Comment: @Galik I don't think so. The answer in that question is clear enough, even with its own example. People can just ignore the question content and focus on the answer.

Comment: @liliscent: People *can* ignore that, but they rarely do. Question quality matters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. You're getting a const reference to a tuple of non-const references to ints.  You're then breaking out that tuple into two non-const references.  To make the int references const, you need to make the int references const:

   ```
   auto const& [xb, yb] = std::tuple<const int&, const int&>(xa, ya);
   ```
2. The tuple you are creating is an unnamed temporary, so you can't bind a non-const reference to it, even though that reference is itself unnamed.